# WhatsApp login error

Tags: c#, whatsapp

I am using [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Whatsapp.NET/) API to connect & send message to Whatsapp. Here is the code.

```
WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp("your number", "your password", "Name", false, false);
wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
{
    Response.Write("connect");
    wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phno,data) =>
    {
        wa.SendMessage("to", "msg");
    };

    wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
    {
        Response.Write("login failed"+data);
    };
    wa.Login();
};
wa.OnConnectFailed+= (ex)=>
{
    Response.Write("connection failed");
}
wa.Connect();
wa.Disconnect();
```

But with this line

```
wa.Login();
wa.Disconnect();
```

I am getting the error

```
No overload for method 'Login' takes '0' arguments
```

I have read several tutorials but none of them used any arguments in the login method. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: i guess, login method needs args

Comment: What could be the arguments ?

Comment: I am trying your code on my sample application.. So let me try

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava Look at the intellisense? Or the documentation for your library. You really need to research more before asking a question.

Comment: Is your password correct?

Comment: @RachitPatel, Password is not the problem. At compile time, the code is giving error.

Comment: I have created .net windows application and its working fine at my end

Comment: @Rob, documentation is not given at that particular site

Comment: what are you passing in password?

Comment: password should be imei no

Comment: @AmitSoni, I used WART to generate the password. Here you can see. http://findnerd.com/list/view/Sending-WhatsApp-Message-in--Net/4502/

Comment: @RachitPatel, have you used the same API that I am using i.e. https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Whatsapp.NET/1.2.2

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava What does your intellisense say, then? What version of the whatsapp package are you using?

Comment: The `login` method expects a `byte[]` as its parameter (`nextChallenge`). Pass `null` if you don't have one. *Hint: When you can't find the documentation, go to the github repository and rip apart the code to see what you are after.*

Comment: @Abhitalks, Its working. Now error gone. Thanks!! You should write it as answer. Also if possible, could you identify the problem with `wa.Disconnect();`

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava: I already gave you a hint. Here is the github repo - https://github.com/rafaellincoln/WhatsAPINet. Open it up and go through the code. There is a test project there as well. Open that project and it will give you a lot of help.

Comment: @Abhitalks, Thanks. It really helped.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/mgp25/wart API

Answer (score 1):

this works fine for me

```
WhatsUserManager manager = new WhatsUserManager();
            user = manager.CreateUser(txtphonenumber.Text, "NAME");
            var thread = new Thread(ThreadState =>
            {
                UpdateTextBox textbox = UpdateDataTextBox;
                WhatSocket.Create(txtphonenumber.Text, textBoxPass.Text, textBoxNick.Text, true);
                WhatSocket.Instance.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
                {
                    if (txtstatus.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        Invoke(textbox, txtstatus, "connected...");
                    }

                    WhatSocket.Instance.OnLoginSuccess += (phone, data) =>
                    {
                        //WhatSocket.Instance.PollMessages(true);
                        WhatSocket.Instance.SendMessage("SENDER_NUMBER", "TEST");
                        Invoke(textbox, txtstatus, "Login Success...");
                    };
                    WhatSocket.Instance.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
                    {
                        if (txtstatus.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            Invoke(textbox, txtstatus, string.Format("\r\n Login Failed : {0}", data));
                        }
                    };
                    WhatSocket.Instance.OnGetMessage += (node,from,id,name,message,receipt_sent) => 
                    {
                        Invoke(textbox, txtstatus, string.Format("\r\n Name : {0}, Message : {1}", name,message));
                    };
                    WhatSocket.Instance.Login();
                };
                WhatSocket.Instance.OnConnectFailed += (ex) =>
                {
                    if (txtstatus.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        Invoke(textbox, txtstatus, string.Format("\r\n Connect Failed : {0}", ex.StackTrace));
                    }
                };
                WhatSocket.Instance.Connect();
            }) { IsBackground = true };
            thread.Start();
```

Comment: Where its API link is ?

Comment: I am getting the error `the type or namespace name WhatsUserManager could not be found`